# MapFragment with TextView and Buttons in separate UI segment

Tags: android, google-maps, textview, supportmapfragment

I have a problem with a MapFragment and I don't know how I can make it to NOT fill the screen. I need to have a MapFragment to stop at my textview. Im attaching a picture that better describe how I need it to look.
Right now my MapFragment fills the screen and the textview is placed on top of the MapFragment.

I then have two buttons that is on top of my textview. This is OK.

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Hope you can help!

here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linelay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.MapsActivity"
            tools:layout="@layout/activity_main"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ToggleButton
        android:text="ToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="clearMap"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/frame" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your map is inside a LinearLayout, using all of its space, which in turn is set to use its parent (RelativeLayout) entire space (match_parent).

The layout_weight for the map is doing nothing, since it is inside a LinearLayout with nothing else. Maybe what you want is to have the layout_weight set for the LinearLayout. 

Also keep in mind that layout_weight works best (and is much faster) if the parent is a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  Use a LinearLayout as the outer Layout, and use layout weights to define the height for different sections.

This is better than defining heights for either of the sections using hard-coded dp values. Using layout weights for the height will better dynamically adjust with different screen sizes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.danielnugent.mapapplication.MapsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".8">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView Text Here"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="14sp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:

[image]